# EF + MVC3: How to Create DropDownList Filter when page model is IPagedList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, filter, ienumerable

I've been following the excellent tutorial from asp.net about creating pagination and filtering: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I now want to add another filter using a dropdownlist which will filter my projects. I found another tutorial about this and followed it: http://chikkanti.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/dropdownlist-based-filtering-in-mvc-3-using-entityframeworkedm-modalfirst-method/

However, when I run it, I got an error about the dropdownlist not being of type IEnumerable. This made sense as the page model is of type IPagedList.
How can I add a dropdownlist filter to the page with page model IPagedList?

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult SearchNames(string ddlcontent, int? page)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        var list = new List<string>();
        var nameqry = from n in db.tblProjects
                      select n.ProjectName;
        list.AddRange(nameqry.Distinct());
        ViewBag.ddlcontent = new SelectList(list);
        //var names = from m in db.tblProjects
        //            select m;
        var tbldefectdetails = db.tblDefectDetails.Include(t => t.tblBugLocation).Include(t => t.tblBugType).Include(t => t.tblBusinessUnit).Include(t => t.tblDefectDiscoveryMethod).Include(t => t.tblProject).Include(t => t.tblLanguage);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlcontent))
            {
                tbldefectdetails = tbldefectdetails.Where(s => s.tblProject.ProjectName.ToUpper().Contains(ddlcontent.ToUpper()));
            }
        return View(tbldefectdetails.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

DropdownList in View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<EDTToolMVC.Models.tblDefectDetail>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Early Defect Tracking Tool - Home";
}

<h2>SearchNames</h2>
@using (@Html.BeginForm(“SearchNames”, “Names”, FormMethod.Get))
{
@Html.DropDownList(“ddlcontent”, “All”)<input type=”submit” value=”Filter” />;
}
```

IPagedList:

```
namespace PagedList
{
// Summary:
//     Represents a subset of a collection of objects that can be individually accessed
//     by index and containing metadata about the superset collection of objects
//     this subset was created from.
//
// Type parameters:
//   T:
//     The type of object the collection should contain.
//
// Remarks:
//     Represents a subset of a collection of objects that can be individually accessed
//     by index and containing metadata about the superset collection of objects
//     this subset was created from.
public interface IPagedList<out T> : IPagedList, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
{
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the number of elements contained on this page.
    int Count { get; }

    // Summary:
    //     Gets the element at the specified index.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   index:
    //     The zero-based index of the element to get.
    T this[int index] { get; }

    // Summary:
    //     Gets a non-enumerable copy of this paged list.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A non-enumerable copy of this paged list.
    IPagedList GetMetaData();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the viewmodel, so it contains the elements of your dropdown list. Or inherits from IPagedList.

```
class MyViewModel<T>{
  public IPagedList<T> Model {get;set;}
  public IList<something> DropdownElements {get;set;}
}
```

Or to make it reusable, create a base Viewmodel, or a base View class, that your ViewModels, or Views inherit from that contains functions to that implement common reusable "services" like this.